# Transforming a data frame to wide table with R

Tags: r

I've got following data frame:

```
    T  S    V
1  s0  A  2.5
2  s1  A    1
3  s2  A    3
4  s0  B  5.6
5  s1  B    7
6  s0  C    8
```

I would like to turn it into:

```
   s0  s1  s2
A 2.5   1   3
B 5.6   7   0
C   8   0   0
```

So that it can be used by a `chisq.test`.

I've tried the following, which only takes into account the occurrence but not the values:

```
table(d$T, d$S)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
xtabs(V ~ S + T, data=d)  #
```

You are actually stretching the definition of contingency table a bit but I have not had problems with fractional values as long as there are no repeated levels. If there were you might need to use `tapply` with an appropriate aggregation function, and "correct" or "zero-out" NA's if you wanted zeros in the missing factor levels.

```
> td <- tapply(d$V, list(d$S, d$T), sum)
> td[is.na(td) ] <- 0
> td
   s0 s1 s2
A 2.5  1  3
B 5.6  7  0
C 8.0  0  0
```

There are quite a few other methods that might work for this "long" to "wide" transformaltion. The plyr package has a more consistent syntax for it's methods. Look at the `dcast` function in plyr. There is also the `reshape` function in base-R and search SO for worked examples. The `data.table` package is deserving of a good look if you start needing speed. It's got a different syntax than plyr and needs bit of mental adjustment, but it has gained a following among "power useRs".